# Given an IANA Timezone and a local time, parse it into a Maybe Posix?

Tags: datetime, timezone, utc, elm

Is there a way in Elm to take a local time (such as the string `2019-03-18T09:10:12.4`; **no offset specifed**) and a timezone (such as `Australia/Sydney`) to a possible [Posix](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#Posix) value (i.e, that time converted to UTC), without using ports?

---

There's [waratuman/time-extra](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/waratuman/time-extra/1.1.0/Time-Extra#fromIso8601Date), but it seems to only work on the Date portion. And sadly [rtfeldman/elm-iso8601-date-strings](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-iso8601-date-strings/latest) doesn't take [timezones](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/timezone-data/latest/).

In JS, there's options such as [moment-tz](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) and [date-fns-timezone](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.27/docs/Time-Zones#date-fns-timezone), but it would be much simpler to avoid JS interop for frequent date parsing.

Comment: Library recommendations are explicitly off-topic on SO. See the [help/on-topic]. You should just ask about a specific task instead, and still make references to shortcomings in existing libraries. Solutions to that task might then use a library, or several, or none at all.

Comment: There's a lot of comments about this in the "Future Plans" section [of the elm time docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/#future-plans), and on the discourse site linked from there.   Personally, I would hope the Elm community would consider an approach similar to [the one Luxon uses](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/zones.html#luxon-works-with-time-zones), which interrogates the built-in Intl APIs for time zone data.  I'm not currently an Elm user, but you might suggest such a route on their discourse site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By combining [justinmimbs/time-extra](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/time-extra/latest/Time-Extra) and [justinmimbs/timezone-data](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/timezone-data/latest/), you should be able to get valid posix entirely in Elm.

Demo: https://ellie-app.com/54tyw9yvsQga1

---

First, you need to convert your `timestampWithoutTimezone` to [`Parts`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/time-extra/latest/Time-Extra#Parts):

```
toParts : String -> Maybe Parts
toParts timestampWithoutTimezone =
    timestampWithoutTimezone
        |> Regex.find regex
        |> List.map .submatches
        |> List.head
        |> Maybe.andThen Maybe.Extra.combine
        |> Maybe.andThen listToParts

regex : Regex
regex =
    Maybe.withDefault Regex.never <|
        Regex.fromString "^(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})T(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})\\.(\\d)$"


monthLookup : Dict String Month
monthLookup =
    Dict.fromList [ ( "01", Jan ), ( "02", Feb ), ( "03", Mar ), ( "04", Apr ), ( "05", May ), ( "06", Jun ), ( "07", Jul ), ( "08", Aug ), ( "09", Sep ), ( "10", Oct ), ( "11", Nov ), ( "12", Dec ) ]


listToParts : List String -> Maybe Parts
listToParts list =
    let
        toInt : Int -> Maybe Int
        toInt index =
            list |> List.Extra.getAt index |> Maybe.andThen String.toInt
    in
    Maybe.map2 Parts
        (toInt 0)
        (list |> List.Extra.getAt 1 |> Maybe.andThen (\month -> Dict.get month monthLookup))
        |> Maybe.andThen (\parts -> Maybe.map5 parts (toInt 2) (toInt 3) (toInt 4) (toInt 5) (toInt 6))
```

Then, using [`partsToPosix`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/time-extra/latest/Time-Extra#partsToPosix) with the appropriate [`Zone`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/timezone-data/latest/TimeZone#zones) you can get a posix value:

```
toPosix : Time.Zone -> String -> Maybe Posix
toPosix zone timestampWithoutTimezone =
    timestampWithoutTimezone
        |> toParts
        |> Maybe.map (Time.Extra.partsToPosix zone)
```

The library author recommends you store evaluated Zone values in your model:

```
model = { zone = TimeZone.australia__sydney () }

toPosix model.zone "2019-03-18T09:10:12.4"
```

Comment: I admire your persistence, but it really seems like there ought to be an easier way to accomplish this :)

Answer (score 2):

If we can assume that all of your dates come without a timezone, and that you always want to cast them to `Australia/Sydney` before converting them to Posix, you should be able to just concatenate the offset yourself to create `2019-03-18T09:10:12.4+11:00`:

```
toPosix : String -> String -> Maybe Posix
toPosix timezone timestampWithoutTimezone =
    let
        timestampWithTimezone = timestampWithoutTimezone ++ timezone
    in
        timestampWithTimezone |> toTime |> Result.toMaybe


{- If you always want to use Australia/Sydney -}

localPosix =
    toPosix "+11:00"

posix =
    localPosix "2019-03-18T09:10:12.4"

{- Custom timezone -}

posix =
    toPosix "+11:00" "2019-03-18T09:10:12.4"
```

Comment: Yes, this is the workaround we're using at the moment. However, it's important for it to be accurate even in the presence of Daylight Savings.